# OSClass Save Text field admin plugin

Tags: osclass

i have almost completed a plugin. It is all working.

All i need to do is save the preference of the text field in the admin panel

does anyone know how this is done

i need to save and return saved data back to text field

Comment: please provide some code ilustration what you have o far

Answer (score 0):

osc_set_preference('name', 'value', 'section'); and osc_get_preference('name', 'section');

'section' by default is 'osclass' and I suggest you to change to something like 'myplugin' so it will be unique